# Javascript immediate function call from external function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the immediate function defined in test1.js on click of the button defined under html file. It always throws error "test is undefined". I am little bit aware that being a immediate function, it calls immediately, and so it returns the "undefined error". But is there any way I can call the immediate function (access methods, properties, etc.) on click of the button?

Thank you in advance.

```js
//test1.js

var test = (function(){
alert(window);
var tmp = 'hello';
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
  
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="ClickMe!"  />
  
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn.addEventListener("click",fun1,false);

function fun1(){
alert(test.tmp);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your IIFE returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify your code so that the IIFE returns an object with a `tmp` property. Such as

```
var test = (function(){
alert(window);
var tmp = 'hello';
return {tmp:tmp};
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly return an object containing any data you want made available after you run the IIFE. (Just add the return as I did to the snippet below).

```js
//test1.js

var test = (function(){
  alert(window);
  // you need to return any values you want accessible
  return {
    tmp: "hello"
  }
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
  
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="ClickMe!"  />
  
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn.addEventListener("click",fun1,false);

function fun1(){
alert(test.tmp);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```